# QtNetworkAccessManager doesn't work after network restart and issues QNetworkReply:UnknownNetworkError

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

I am a beginner in QT. I have a custom application which sends and receives information from my http server. When the network services are restarted, the Qt application doesn't connect with the server and issues network error as below. Also, after restart the issue gets resolved.

Here is my error log:

> Network error QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError received
> requestFinished, code: 500 url: "xxxx/xxxx/xxxx" (unknown:0) -
> QIODevice::read (QDisabledNetworkReply): device not open

I have searched in forums but I couldn't get a solution to the same.

Comment: How to reset the network and reconnect with the existing qt object without restarting the  application? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Could you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Abdurahmon  I cannot share the example code since its not an opensource code. Here is the snippet for your reference.
QNetworkAccessManager _networkMgr;

Class constructor:
============
Cloud::Cloud(xx parent_object),
_networkMgr()
{
    connect(&_networkMgr, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, Cloud::requestFinished);
    connect(&_networkMgr, &QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors, this, &Cloud::sslError);
}

This application runs in a Linux based device. When I restart the network, the next API call to the server fails with QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError